# Max-filter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I like to find the envelope of an audio signal using matlab, i.e. the red signal in the picture. I have implemented a max-filter but the implementation is very slow. Does matlab have a built in max-filter or some other function that can calculate the envelope? (I have found a median filter but no max-filter)

[image: max-filter applied to an audio signal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in max filter, but there are user generated functions at the [MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). For example:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24902-envelope

Comment: Thanks! I took a while (15min) to log in to the site, but the envelope function works fine!